# How to change the color of content text in Alert Dialog box android

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am stuck and i am not getting how to do. In my apps there is an AlertDialog Box with List View containing an image and a text but The text is coming white in color and is not visible i want to change the color of the Text in the ListView.

Please help...

The snippets are as follows:

```
  final String[] items = new String[]{"From Gallery", "From Camera"};
        final Integer[] icons = new Integer[]{R.drawable.camera_picker, R.drawable.gallery_picker};
        ListAdapter adapter = new CameraPickAdapter(StataComplaintActivity.this, items, icons);
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
        //AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.CustomAlertDialogTheme));

        builder.setTitle("Select Image From")
                .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (item == 0) {
                            loadImageFromGallery();
                        } else if (item == 1) {
                            takePictureIntent();
                        } else {
                        }
                    }
                }).show();
```

**CameraPickAdapter.java**

```
public class CameraPickAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private List<Integer> images;

    public CameraPickAdapter(Context context, List<String> items, List<Integer> images) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
        this.images = images;
    }

    public CameraPickAdapter(Context context, String[] items, Integer[] images) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
        this.images = Arrays.asList(images);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(images.get(position), 0, 0, 0);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(
                (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        return view;
    }

}
```

The Dialog is as:

[image]

Comment: can you put code of CameraPickAdapter?

Comment: @MoradiyaAkash I added the code for CameraPickAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use context reference to set custom or default color to TextView in adapter :

```
private Context context;
```

initialize context instance in constructor :

```
this.context = context;
```

Now set custom or default text color in getView() using context reference :

```
textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.custom_color_name)); // custom color
```

**OR**

```
textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)); // default color
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your adapter code by,

```
public class CameraPickAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private List<Integer> images;

    public CameraPickAdapter(Context context, List<String> items, List<Integer> images) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
        this.images = images;
    }

    public CameraPickAdapter(Context context, String[] items, Integer[] images) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
        this.images = Arrays.asList(images);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(images.get(position), 0, 0, 0);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(
                (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution with an extended ArrayAdapter that allows icons.

See design notes for dialogs at http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/dialogs.html Iconogaphy at http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html and IconPacks at http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Note that the size for these looks pretty good at 48 x 48 dp, which isn't a bundled size, so you'll have to scale your own icon from the downloads.

USAGE:

```
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String [] items = new String[] {"From Gallery", "From Camera"};
        final Integer[] icons = new Integer[] {R.drawable.dialog_gallery_icon, R.drawable.dialog_camera_icon};
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapterWithIcon(getActivity(), items, icons);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Select Image")
            .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }).show();
    }
```

ArrayAdapterWithIcon.java

```
   public class ArrayAdapterWithIcon extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

   private List<Integer> images;

   public ArrayAdapterWithIcon(Context context, List<String> items, List<Integer> images) {
       super(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
       this.images = images;
   }

   public ArrayAdapterWithIcon(Context context, String[] items, Integer[] images) {
       super(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
       this.images = Arrays.asList(images);
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
       TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
       textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(images.get(position), 0, 0, 0);
       textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(
               (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12,               getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
       return view;
   }

   }
```